# Удалить лишние списки сохранив значения

Tags: python, list, numpy

Есть список

```
[[12, 0, 6], [12, 12, 5], [20, 30, 0]]
```

Желаемый вывод:

```
[12, 0, 6, 12, 12, 5, 20, 30, 0]
```

Comment: numpy.ndarray.flatten `https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html``

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
old_list = [[12, 0, 6], [12, 12, 5], [20, 30, 0]]
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    [new_list.append(j) for j in i]
print(new_list)
```

Или другой вариант, если сократить:

```
new_list = []
[[new_list.append(j) for j in i] for i in [[12, 0, 6], [12, 12, 5], [20, 30, 0]]]
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Какой смысл использовать списковое сокращение, если вы не используете то, что оно генерирует? Используйте обычные циклы тогда, если хотите делать `append`. Либо не используйте `append`, если хотите делать список через списковое сокращение.

Comment: @CrazyElf Использую для сокращения кол-ва строк. Как пришло в голову, так и решил. Без append не знаю, как сразу в список

Comment: `new_list = [j for i in [[12, 0, 6], [12, 12, 5], [20, 30, 0]] for j in i ]` - это ещё короче, чем ваш код, и без излишеств. Вы почитайте про списковые сокращения, там всё написано.

Comment: CrazyElf, я пытался так сделать, но у меня не получалось. Про list comprehension я знаю, сейчас перечитал, но мне не помогло. Решение в 1 строку слишком сложно для меня, я не понимаю конструкции j for i.

Comment: А вы представьте, что перед каждым `for` стоит перевод строки. А то, что перед самым первым `for` наоборот идёт в конце. Это обычные циклы `for`, просто хитро записанные в одну строку.

Comment: Спасибо, чисто следуя этому правилу, сейчас-таки смог собрать эту конструкцию, по логике не получалось.